# What is the use of the "$" in regex pattern?

Tags: java, regex

A pattern has the use of these `$`, what is its use? Would be to complement **similar** to `*`?

Code

```
    Pattern tempoPattern = Pattern.compile("s$");
    Matcher tempoMatcher = tempoPattern.matcher(normalizado);

    Pattern bytesPattern = Pattern.compile("(k|m|g)b$");
```

Comment: `$` matches the end of a string in RegEx.

Comment: This , as per document, matches the  end of line . http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> **Boundary matchers**
>
> $    The end of a line