# What does $ do in this reqular expression

Tags: regex, postgresql-9.3

`[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

I want to know what is the use of `$` in regular expression generally.

I searched in net and got `matches at the end of the string`

but didn't understand practically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851024.

Comment: check https://regex101.com/r/vH0iN5/8

Comment: $ is an anchor that will represent the end of a string. Have a look here : http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: Check out a live regex editor (e.g. http://www.phpliveregex.com ), where you can fiddle around with various expressions and see the effect. Compare, say, `[a-z_]+` and `[a-z_]+$`.

Answer (score 0):

Your quote is pretty clear, once you've understood. It means that the string that you are looking for, must **end** with the content of the regular expression.

In this case, the string must end like that ˋ[a-zA-Z0-9]ˋ